# Массивы и вывод данных из них PHP

Tags: php, массивы

1. создать массивы с названиями месяцев и днями недели
2. вывести текущую дату в формате "Сегодня *день* *название месяца* *год* года. Это *день недели из массива*"

Я первый раз в жизни вижу php, подскажите пожалуйста, если уж не решение задачи, то хотя бы что нужно использовать для её реализации, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста. Вот [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/968fdb0334256916878be8a94179d0d3c03f8325):

```
$months = [
    1 => "Января",
    2 => "Февраля",
    3 => "Марта",
    4 => "Апреля",
    5 => "Мая",
    6 => "Июня",
    7 => "Июля",
    8 => "Августа",
    9 => "Сетября",
    10 => "Октября",
    11 => "Ноября",
    12 => "Декабря",
    ];

$days = [
    1 => "Понедельник",
    2 => "Вторник",
    3 => "Среда",
    4 => "Четверг",
    5 => "Пятница",
    6 => "Суббота",
    7 => "Воскресенье"
    ];

$day = date("j");
$month = date("n");
$year = date("Y");
$week_day = date("N");

$ru_month =  $months[$month];
$ru_day = $days[$week_day];

echo "Сегодня $day $ru_month $year года. Это $ru_day";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё было проще, чем я думал))

Comment: Если ответ вас устраивает, будь добры пометить его как Ответ на вопрос